# how to get child values from a radio button using PDFBOX

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfbox

how to get child values from a radio button using PDFBOX, Below is my code where 
`row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()` will return me the field name with type as `RadioButton`
Wth help of Field name i need to get the child values associated to that current field name .
Now with the below piece of code it throws error on line :

```
foreach (object kid in kids)  ----> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Code :

```
if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == FieldType.RadioButton.ToString())
{
     radioButtonsList.TryGetValue(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),out index);
     string RadiValue = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     java.util.ArrayList kids = (java.util.ArrayList)pdfFields.getKids();
           foreach (object kid in kids )
           {
              if (kid is PDCheckbox)
                 {
                    PDCheckbox checkbox = (PDCheckbox)kid;
                    RName = checkbox.getOnValue();
                 }
              possibleValues.Add(RName); 
             }
```

Comment: String RadiValue  will the Field name of type radiobutton

Comment: I guess , PdfFields.getKids() consider the all fields with respect to PDFform .. but how to set it current field name using pdfbox